# Checking if an image is in 200dpi in java

Tags: java, image, pdfbox

I would like to check if an image in a pdf is in 200dpi or not and also whether its in color or not in java currently I am using pdfbox to extract images from PDF  But if we can do this using any other free library in java that will also work.

In Pdfbox I am able to get the pdxObjectImage for the images present in the pdf but many at times it happens that their is no metadata present in the images that are extracted from these pdfs.

```
String key = (String) imageIter.next();
PDXObjectImage pdxObjectImage = (PDXObjectImage)pageImages.get(key);
PDMetadata metadata=pdxObjectImage.getMetadata();
if (metadata == null) {
    System.out.println("No Metadata found for this image.");
} else {                
    try {
        xmlInputStream = metadata.createInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
xmlInputStream = metadata.createInputStream();
```

So is their a way to calculate the dpi for images . For finding whether its color or not can I use this

```
pdxObjectImage.getColorSpace().getJavaColorSpace().isCS_sRGB()
```

or is their any other better technique for doing both the things

How can we do this in java.

Comment: Code is better than words.

Comment: Edited the question to include wht I am able to achieve as of now.

Comment: I am extracting image from the PDF file using pdfbox into the pdxObjectImage object and then trying to perform operations for checking color and dpi . So i am not checking the DPI of pdf file but the image.

Comment: So any suggestions for getting dpi of image in pdxObjectImage object

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472711/dpi-of-image-extracted-from-pdf-with-pdfbox

Comment: What is the ctmNew object in that example .
is it this 
Matrix ctmNew = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();

Answer (score 0):

I have not used pdfbox. But if you can extract the image using pdfbox from the pdf, then you can use apache [common-imaging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/index.html) lib for the further processing. The advantage of using this lib is it provides a lot of image manipulations.

The sample code snippet may be helpful for you -

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.imaging.ImageInfo;
import org.apache.commons.imaging.ImageReadException;
import org.apache.commons.imaging.Imaging;

public class ImageingTest{


    private static File fileName = new File("/home/razib/Desktop/img/cactus.jpg");

    private static ImageInfo imageInfo;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int physicalWidthDpi = 0;
        int physicalHeightDpi = 0;

        try {


            imageInfo = Imaging.getImageInfo(fileName);
            physicalWidthDpi = imageInfo.getPhysicalWidthDpi();
            physicalHeightDpi = imageInfo.getPhysicalHeightDpi();

            System.out.println("File Name: " + fileName.getName() + " File Format: " +imageInfo.getFormatName());
            System.out.println("Dimension: " +imageInfo.getHeight() +"X"+ imageInfo.getWidth());
            System.out.println("physicalWidthDpi: " +physicalWidthDpi 
                    +"\nphysicalHeightDpi: " +physicalHeightDpi);

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("COLOR_TYPE_BW: " +(imageInfo.getColorType()==ImageInfo.COLOR_TYPE_BW));
            System.out.println("COLOR_TYPE_CMYK: " +(imageInfo.getColorType()==ImageInfo.COLOR_TYPE_CMYK));
            System.out.println("COLOR_TYPE_GRAYSCALE: " +(imageInfo.getColorType()==ImageInfo.COLOR_TYPE_GRAYSCALE));
            System.out.println("COLOR_TYPE_RGB: " +(imageInfo.getColorType()==ImageInfo.COLOR_TYPE_RGB));
            System.out.println("COLOR_TYPE_YCbCr: " +(imageInfo.getColorType()==ImageInfo.COLOR_TYPE_YCbCr));
            System.out.println("COLOR_TYPE_YCC: " +(imageInfo.getColorType()==ImageInfo.COLOR_TYPE_YCC));
            System.out.println("COLOR_TYPE_YCCK: " +(imageInfo.getColorType()==ImageInfo.COLOR_TYPE_YCCK));
            System.out.println("COLOR_TYPE_OTHER: " +(imageInfo.getColorType()==ImageInfo.COLOR_TYPE_OTHER));
            System.out.println("COLOR_TYPE_UNKNOWN: " +(imageInfo.getColorType()==ImageInfo.COLOR_TYPE_UNKNOWN));

        } catch (ImageReadException e) {
            //Handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This won't help, because except for some JPG images, the extracted images don't have any meta data within.